Using an OpenMDAO ExplicitComponent to calculate derivatives
I'm using Dymos to optimise a set of control values for a system, but would like to be able to use their derivatives in the optimisation's constraints and objective function. Is there any way that I can use an OpenMDAO component to differentiate them?
I thought something like this might work:
phase.add_control('ctrl', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True, rate_source='<another component?>', targets=['ctrl'])
where ctrl is an input to the OpenMDAO ExplicitComponent defining the system dynamics, and the rate_source is connected to another component which somehow converges on the true control rate (derivative of ctrl) as the collocation defects are driven to zero by the solver. I'm not sure if this would be a good approach, or quite how to do it? I'm also concerned that the control rates, if calculated in such a way, wouldn't be correct until the collocation defects are eliminated, and that this might lead the solver astray during the solution process?
Many thanks for any help.

In dymos, controls don't have a rate source. Controls are merely parameter values passed at different points (nodes) in time of the trajectory.
If you want to integrate the output of another component and use it as your control, then ctrl is a state as far as dymos is concerned.
Dymos states can have controls, parameters, other states, or ODE system outputs serve as their rate source. Consider the double integrator where u is the control input being given to the problem, but then we integrate it twice - once to obtain the value of the velocity state v, and a second time to obtain the value of the position state x.
It sounds like your your situation, you want a component that computes some output ctrl_dot, and then add a state that uses ctrl_dot as its rate source?
Am I understanding your issue correctly?

Hi Rob, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure this is quite the same, but I could be wrong. I'd like the system to be able to control the deflection angle (ctrl in my example) rather than its rate, as I think it would be more difficult for the optimiser if deflection rate were the control input. However, I'd still like to get the derivative of the deflection angle trajectory produced by the optimiser, as I'd like to put some constraints on this deflection rate, and use it as part of the optimisation (i.e. to minimise the total change of control angle as a regularisation on the output).

While I have you here (since this probably isn't a post-able question on its own), could I ask about my optimisation performance? Just that it's taking a very long time to solve compared to the Dymos examples, and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong which might be slowing it unnecessarily. I've tried to compare run times against systems of a similar size/complexity in other papers and it doesn't seem too far wrong (assuming they're set up well). It's a 12-state system (plus others for output), with quite a lot of coupling in the differential equations, four control inputs...

...The partial derivates are calculated using Jax, and each iteration of the dynamics involves an interpolation, performed by the Interpax Python library. I've checked the partials with the check_partials method in Dymos and the gradient errors look okay (the largest absolute error is 0.00012, much smaller for complex step, although this only works if I disable the interpolation so it's not a true representation). With IPOPT it can take hours to solve (usually with one grid refinement), and even still often ends with an error message, or only 'solves to an acceptable level'...

... The primal error often gets down to e-14 or so but the dual error struggles, getting stuck at about e-3/-4 at best, and animating the state discretisation nodes/collocation points shows that they do find a good solution quite quickly but then stay put and jitter for the rest of the time. However if the gradients are okay I'm not sure what's happening. This might just be the normal behaviour of a system like this, but I don't really have a reference point for these kinds of optimisation problems.

That was longer than expected - I can turn it into a proper SO question...

I forgot to mention: the Jacobian shape pre-grid-refinement is (6374, 5249) - it takes ~99s to compute the sparsity and ~18s to compute the colouring. Post-refinement it's (9824, 6449); it takes ~156s to compute the sparsity and ~46s for the colouring. All of this is being done on a very powerful desktop computer (although the software as written doesn't utilise many of the cores).

Could I request that we take this to a github discussion? I just enabled discussions on the dymos repo:  https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/discussions

I've just reposted the question there with some extra information. Thank you for your help.
